# Angular-translate doesn't reflect in view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angularjs, now i going to add angular-translate library

```
 <jb-sub-header sub-header-label="Match Details"></jb-sub-header>
```

In above tag `jb-sub-header` is the component and `sub-header-label` is an attribute, but i dont know how i translate this "match details".

Comment: Probably you should write `sub-header-label="{{ match_details | translate }}"`

Comment: it not works.if i put above code it hide the string

Comment: You should have match_details key in your translation .json file

Comment: yes,but it not works

Answer (score 1):

Use the `$translate` service, which can easily be injected in your controller. You can assign a translation string as follows in a variable of the scope:

```
$translate(['YOUR_KEY_HERE']).then(function (translations) {
  $scope.subheader = translations['YOUR_KEY_HERE'];
});
```

This way, `$scope.subheader` will have the translated string, which can then be used in the directive as follows:

```
<jb-sub-header sub-header-label="{{subheader}}"></jb-sub-header>
```

See the **How it works** section in [this guide](https://angular-translate.github.io/).